# Bad text in Notice for Quantcast Measurement

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, terms-of-service

In iPhone → Settings → Stack Exchange → Notices → Quantcast Management, the text near the end is messed up.

[image: Quantcast Management]

Version: Stack Exchange iOS App Version 0.1.25

Comment: How do you user a setting? Or ring a root?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These notices are implanted into the Settings bundle from source text during our build process.  I fixed the typo on "user" (should be "use"), but the source text doesn't have the stray xml markup, so there's probably a scripting problem somewhere.  I'll get this fixed soon.

**Update** I'm still not entirely sure what the problem was.  It was some kind of bad interaction between the shell and PlistBuddy's `Import` command.  I changed the relevant build step to avoid `Import` and it seems to be working now, and it should be apparent in the next build (0.1.50 or later).

Comment: Verified fixed in 0.1.50.