# Bad text in Terms of Service

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, terms-of-service

In iPhone → Settings → Stack Exchange → Notices → SE Network Terms of Service, there's an extra "s" after the first paragraph.

[image]

<sub>([it's not a plural "s" so please don't hurt me.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9694/204869))</sub>

---

**Also**, the text under "section 14. Community Moderators" is missing (compare with [web version](https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service)).

---

**Also**, the sections above "Designated Agent" near the end are not properly paragraphed.

---

Version: Stack Exchange iOS App Version 0.1.25

Comment: They put those there to check if somebody is actually reading them. So congrats, you have passed ;-).

Comment: I think editor was trying to save that text using Ctrl+S.

Comment: @Nimesh that's what I figured the first time I saw it, but it's not the case.  The stray 's' was never there in the source text, and only appeared after `PlistBuddy "Import...`

Answer (score 7):

Thanks for reading, and thanks for catching it.  This will be fixed in the next build.

**Update**: well this was tricker than I was expecting.  I just fixed [Bad text in Notice for Quantcast Measurement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225223/136973), and it took care of this one too.  Will be apparent in next build (0.1.50 or later).

Comment: Uh... what happened to [meta-tag:status-completed]?

Comment: I don't usually do that until I've actually made the change ;-)

Comment: Not fixed yet in 0.1.49. Will re-test in next build.

Comment: @Pang, I said in my answer that "next build" is 0.1.50 or later.

Comment: (v0.1.50) Hmmm... the text under section 11 is missing. Also, some parts between "Reporting Copyright Infringements" and "Filing Copyright Counterclaims" seems missing when compared to the [web version](http://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service). Are the mobile and web versions supposed to be the same? Anyway, I didn't check every paragraph, so there could be more.

Comment: Parts of this report don't seem to be completed yet - I came to Meta to report and found this thread. The paragraphs near the end of the terms - specifically, around the Designated Agent, are a bit broken, titles are tacked on to previous paras and there are some blank spaces where it looks like there should either be a list, or an address. Possibly some lists are condensed into long paras as well.