# iOS Settings Acknowledgements error

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

Looks like there is a problem with how the you are communicating with the settings app, as the acknowledgement part does not actually show the notice, but rather some output from what appears to be cocoapods.

[image: main settings]

[image: detail]

- App Version: 1.4.0
- Device: iPhone7,1
- OS Version: Version 9.1 (Build 13B143)

Comment: Reproduced on the latest beta  (1.4.0.250).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next beta build.

When I adopted `use_frameworks!` for the app, I broke down the pods into two targets, `app` and `extensions`.  This moved the acknowledgment file from `Pods/Pods-acknowledgements.plist` to `Pods-app/Pods-app-acknowledgements.plist`, breaking the apparently quite brittle shell script that puts the Notices page together.

On a related note, I also fixed the Quantcast and Terms of Service items' text.  It appears that PlistBuddy's import command is broken ([and we've known this for a while](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225223/bad-text-in-notice-for-quantcast-measurement)) so I rewrote the shell script as a Swift script with better output and error checking.

Since it'll be a while before the next release:

- [AFNetworking](https://cocoapods.org/pods/AFNetworking)
- [Bite](https://cocoapods.org/pods/Bite)
- [Bolts](https://cocoapods.org/pods/Bolts)
- [CocoaLumberjack](https://cocoapods.org/pods/CocoaLumberjack)
- [DTCoreText](https://cocoapods.org/pods/DTCoreText)
- [DTFoundation](https://cocoapods.org/pods/DTFoundation)
- [FBSDKCoreKit](https://cocoapods.org/pods/FBSDKCoreKit)
- [FBSDKLoginKit](https://cocoapods.org/pods/FBSDKLoginKit)
- [GRMustache](https://cocoapods.org/pods/GRMustache)
- [GoogleAnalytics](https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleAnalytics)
- [MMDrawerController](https://cocoapods.org/pods/MMDrawerController)
- [MagicalRecord](https://cocoapods.org/pods/MagicalRecord)
- [Mocktail](https://cocoapods.org/pods/Mocktail)
- [NgKeyboardTracker](https://cocoapods.org/pods/NgKeyboardTracker)
- [Quantcast-Measure](https://cocoapods.org/pods/Quantcast-Measure)
- [SEMarkdownEditor](https://cocoapods.org/pods/SEMarkdownEditor)
- [SEStringUtilities](https://cocoapods.org/pods/SEStringUtilities)
- [SEUICollectionViewLayout](https://cocoapods.org/pods/SEUICollectionViewLayout)
- [SHActionSheetBlocks](https://cocoapods.org/pods/SHActionSheetBlocks)
- [SHAlertViewBlocks](https://cocoapods.org/pods/SHAlertViewBlocks)
- [SVGKit](https://cocoapods.org/pods/SVGKit)
- [SocketRocket](https://cocoapods.org/pods/SocketRocket)
- [TTTAttributedLabel](https://cocoapods.org/pods/TTTAttributedLabel)
- [google-plus-ios-sdk](https://cocoapods.org/pods/google-plus-ios-sdk)

Comment: Is it possible for  to help test the beta build?

Comment: @hhanesand Meta post about that coming later today but [here's the signup sheet](https://docs.google.com/a/stackoverflow.com/forms/d/18ZDfsBm35cV72Gzf88zPaMLQwrSRPwP2__RnPb-uqTs/viewform).